# How many media queries should i use? At what widths?

Tags: css, media-queries

I want my design to be efficient.

I unfortunately have 5 different media queries and think that is a bit too much.
Is there too much work put in with more media queries?

At what pixel amount should I have the media queries at:

I am assuming there needs to be:

- A typical mobile device (how many px?)
- A tablet(how many px?)
- A net book(how many px?)
- A laptop(how many px?)
- Maybe something bigger(how many px?)

Can anyone tell me at what pixel the media queries should run?
I understand I need to use %centages but when i have a giant title in the middle of the screen I need to use a query(or annoying javascript).

Comment: You may want to see how Bootstrap does it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

I recommend this list to get a general idea of what pixels you should use.
Depending on how you layout your site you may need to use more or less queries, as you only need a query for each seperate layout/design of the site. A good choice for basic use would be Smartphone, Tablet, Standard Screen, HD Screen or 4.

Comment: perfect, exactly what i was looking for. I also never though of phone orientation. Very useful!